# Use of Poincare Bendixon Theorem $x'=1-4x+x^2y, y'=3x-x^2y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am having a hard time showing that there is a non-constant periodic trajectory for the system of ODEs:

$$x'=1-4x+x^2y$$ $$y'=3x-x^2y$$

I think that I need to apply Poincare-bendixon theorem but I am not sure how to do this because the theorem is very new to me. An example or help would be much appreciated.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

A little help: You cannot apply the P-B theroem directly because the system has a critical point $(1, 3)$ found by solving equations $x'=0$ and $y'=0$ for $x$ and $y$. You have to analyze the stability of linearized system around $(1, 3)$ and consider a closed region which does not contain the critical point $(1, 3)$ (in this case the P-B theorem is applicable).